# According to Weierstrass theorem, a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded.

Tags: continuity, maxima-minima

What if the function is discontinuous at just one point? Is it bounded anyway?

Why is my example different from the one you proposed?

Comment: Depends on the type of discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily bounded anymore. For instance, take the function
$$f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R,~f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq0\\\frac{1}{x}&x>0\end{cases}$$
It is defined on a closed, bounded interval (this is important: $\frac1x$ or $\tan$ are not counterexamples, since they *are* continuous, they are just not defined everywhere), has one discontinuity, and it is not bounded.

Comment: So how can I prove that this function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2,\qquad\quad\,\, 0\le x\le 1 \\ 2, \qquad\qquad 1 < x \le 4 \\ x-2, \qquad 4 < x \le 5 \end{cases}.$$ is bounded?

Comment: @Veronica All three functions used to define $f$ are continuous and therefore bounded on $[0,5]$.

Comment: So it doesn't count that it is discontinuous at x=1? Which is the difference with your example in which you two continuous function except at x=0?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is discontinuous **only** at $c \in [a,b]$, and depending on the type of discontinuity, then you can say $f$ is bounded in $[a,c), (c, b]$ (but depending on the type of discontinuity!).

You're probably thinking on a removable discontinuity, but take $\tan x$ on $[0, \pi]$ (which is only discontinuous at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but **not** bounded!)

Comment: I was thinking about a piecewise function defined on $[0,5]$, which is discontinuous at x=1. Since I have to use the fact that a bounded function with a finite number of discontinuities is integrable, I wanted to use Weierstrass, but the problem of x=1 remains.